# How to extract specific option value from a plugin?

Tags: javascript, installation, jwplayer, var

I want to extract a specific config value from the jwplayer. i just want to get the file of the video (shown in the player) as an javascript var

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
    file: "video.mp4", });
```

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.
this is the js code for this:

```
var videoURL = jwplayer().getPlaylistItem().file;
console.log(videoURL);
```

Comment: how can i acess this from another js file?

Comment: please explain yourself

Comment: basicly im trying to make a browser extension for sites using the jwplayer to get the video url and for example download it or show the video in the original html 5 video player

Comment: http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1436999-example-adding-a-download-button does this (gets the current file).

Comment: and that is the problem, i cannot access this command from the plugins side. i do not have the right to perform this command